# Como abrir pasta no windows através de um link em HTML?

Tags: html, windows, link, diretório

As pastas são abertas através do navegador. Gostaria que abrissem as próprias pastas do Windows.

Já tentei fazer das seguintes formas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente assim: <a href="file:////home/username">Link</a>

Comment: vc não vai conseguir abrir dessa forma sem determinar o arquivo dentro da pasta. Se vc tem um arquivo index.html, vc deve colocar assim por exemplo `href="file:///D:\index.html"` o browser não vai abrir uma pasta do Windows Explorer na janela... a não ser que seja via ftp pelo servidor ou fazendo um acesso direto na pasta em um servidor, não na máquina local do cliente.

Comment: Eu entendi que você quer abrir o Explorer (gerenciador de arquivos) do windows clicando em um link no navegador, é isso?

Comment: O navegador, normalmente, não abre pastas do seu computador e sim arquivos localizados nas pastas, a partir da tag `<a href="local do arquivo">Título do arquivo</a>`

Answer (score -1):

Abra o arquivo HTML com o Internet Explorer. Isso faz com que uma janela do Windows Explorer seja aberta. É possível escolher uma outra extensão para o arquivo (por exemplo .HTM) e definir para o Internet Explorer abrir como padrão.